# Ordered List - First Digit Hidden in 3-Digit Element Numbers

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an multi-column ordered list with a few hundred entries.

Everything displays fine, **except** for the left-most column. Once the list element numbers reach 3-digits, **the first digit is hidden**. For example, the displayed numbers go **97, 98, 99, 00, 01**, etc.

But this only happens in the leftmost column. The other columns display just fine. The problem occurs 100% of the time, in both Firefox and Chrome. No error message, just incorrect display.

---

I think I found a fix. I changed the  left margin as follows:

margin-left: .5em;

It's not ideal, because it shifts **everything** in the list to the right. There's still some wasted white space, but least I can see all the digits now.

Anyone have a better idea?

Experimenting, I found that setting the list margin like this makes the missing digit visible, but it causes other problems:

li { margin-left: 1.4em; }

The problem now is that **every**

element gets an extra margin causing a great deal of wasted white space in the overall display. Maybe I just can't get there from here.

See the example at **http://www.hymntime.com/tch/mid/met/CM.htm**. You'll have to scroll down, because the problem doesn't occur until you reach element # 100.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this so we can see the 3-digit numbers, but don't waste a lot of screen space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but unless you change your markup and lean it more towards a flexbox method instead of straight up ordered lists, adjusting the left margin on the `<li>'s` is the only way to go and take the hit of the added white space.

Comment: I finally found a workable solution. We have plans to eventually migrate to flex box, but the current code was written many years ago, so we're suck with it for the time being. Any way, the solution was to increase the list's left margin, and decrease the column gap slightly, which took care of the extra space problem. So all looks good (for now). Thanks for taking the time to look at it!